# chmod not working in minGW64 but working Cygwin?

Tags: chmod, cygwin, mingw

I need to do some file permission changes on win10, while I can run this command under cygwin but not in git bash minGW64, can someone help to explain why?

The result as from the cygwin terminal:

```
$ chmod 777 testfile
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 Jon Domain Users 0 Nov  1 11:57 testfile
```

But in mingw64:

```
$ touch test
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon 1049089    0 Nov  1 12:17  test
$ chmod 777 test
$ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon 1049089    0 Nov  1 12:17  test
```

and while I am using chmod I am not even getting error msg.

How can I solve the problem to make the chmod working?

Comment: Mapping POSIX permissions to Windows ACLs is complicated. It's also the kind of thing Cygwin is designed to do. It has an intermediate software layer that translates POSIX-style behavior to native Windows API calls and back. Mingw, OTOH, has a different purpose and programs built with its tools interact directly with Win APIs, i.e. POSIX emulation is not always achievable. (This isn't an answer...I don't know if this is the root cause of your issue...but perhaps useful knowledge generally).

Comment: thank you and yes, I did some research I believe that is the reason, but I didn't find out any possible solutions, too complicated

Comment: Looks like files were created by process other than mingw (since the group is not recognized). If you create the file first in mingw can you then change it to 777? Wondering if issue is existing ACLs that mingw doesn't know how to handle. Separately, can you use alternate/equivalent commands? `chmod a+rwx` or `chmod a=rwx`. Do you see any change if you set the three levels separately? (call `chmod P=rwx` where P is replaced `u`, then `g` then `o`). Just spitballin' but perhaps one of these will reveal something interesting. (Oh, and I assume you've tried as Admin...?)

Answer (score 4):

Cygwin attempts to emulate the POSIX basic permissions using Windows' more complicated ACL. Mingw does not.

However, you are not out of options. From the [Cygwin documentation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html) (affects both):

> Files ending in certain extensions (`.exe`, `.com`, `.lnk`) are assumed to be executable. Files whose first two characters are "`#!`", "`MZ`", or "`:\n`" are also considered to be executable.

Note that the `:` option means you can do this for `.bat` files too, should you desire to.

Edit: I missed the fact that this was using git bash; If this is for a git repo, you don't need to use chmod but can instead directly tell git what you want:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x setupscript.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer the question of how to make `chmod` work on MinGW (it won't), but it does get the right permission bits to show in `ls` output and enables autocomplete of executables when typing `./` followed by *<tab>*.

So, if

- it is possible to modify the file, and
- the executable in question is run by an interpreter,

**add the appropriate shebang as the first line of the file** and MinGW automagically considers it to be executable.

For example, we get the following permissions for the files shown below. Note that no particular file extensions are required.

```console
$ ll
total 3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121 47 Oct 13 07:14 abc*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 43 Oct 13 07:14 def
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121 49 Oct 13 07:16 ghi*
```

File contents:

abc:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
echo I show as an executable.
```

def:

```
echo I do NOT show as executable, though `./def` will run me.
```

ghi:

```py
#! /c/Python39/python
print("MinGW sees me as executable too.")
```